# How to use MATCH function with mixed partial AND strict criteria?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, match

Hi I need to run a match function on several criteria, eg

here is a function which searches N name of a person (column "C) through the rows with the word "person" (in the column "A") who have ID with 1235 (column "F"):

`=INDEX(C:C;MATCH(1;(A:A="person")*(F:F="1235");0);1)`

How to make search it partially, eg if there are spaces before or after the word "person", eg " person" and " person ".

Wildcards, like `*persons*` is not working.

Comment: `(TRIM(A:A)="person")`? or `(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("person";A:A)))`  One note on using match this way. It makes it an array formula and using full column references may slow down the calc if used too many times.  You may want to limit the ranges to the first 10,000 rows or so.

Comment: You can try this `=INDEX(C:C;MATCH(1,(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(" "&"person"&" "," "&A:A&" ")))*(F:F=1235),0))` but as mentioned above ^^^ by @ScottCraner Sir, your Excel Engine will slow down better use absolute references or you formula with in a table structure.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to ignore leading or trailing spaces, you can use `TRIM` in conjunction with an `INDEX` \ `MATCH` \ `INDEX` formula in order to avoid an array formula (which must be entered using Control-Shift-Enter):

```
=INDEX($C:$C, MATCH(1, INDEX((TRIM($A:$A)="person")*($F:$F=12345), 0, 1), 0))
```

[image]

If you want to use wildcards, then you can do that as per Mayukh Bhattacharya's comment. However, I would still suggest avoiding array formulas by combining it with `INDEX` \ `MATCH` \ `INDEX`:

```
=INDEX($C:$C, MATCH(1, INDEX((ISNUMBER(SEARCH("person*male",$A:$A))=TRUE)*($F:$F=12345),0,1), 0))
```

[image]

This will look in column A to see if it contains the word "person", followed by any number of characters (including 0), followed by the word "male".
You can adjust the criteria to anything you like.

### Clarification (in response to comments)

You can add as many different criterion as you need as per below:

```
=INDEX($C:$C, MATCH(1, INDEX(
    (ISNUMBER(SEARCH("person",$A:$A))=TRUE)    ''<-- Criterion 1
    *
    ($F:$F=12345)      ''<-- Criterion 2
    *
    ($B:$B="Anything")    ''<-- Criterion 3
    *
    (SEARCH("Starts With",$D:$D)=1)    ''<-- Criterion 4
,0,1), 0))
```

As you can see you can just keep adding as much criteria as you need.

In this example, it will select the first value in column C, where column A contains the text "person" at least once somewhere in the cell, AND column F = 12345, AND column B = "Anything" (exactly, no leading or trailing spaces etc.), AND column D starts with "Starts With" (this is because we are checking if "starts with" appears at position number 1 within the cell).

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you using index inside the match and not `=INDEX($C:$C, MATCH(1, (TRIM($A:$A)="person")*($F:$F=12345), 0))`? Also isn't `(TRIM($A:$A)="person")*($F:$F=12345)` an array already?

Comment: TRIM function is perfect here! Though, I was looking for a wider option to search with several partial criteria. Many thanks!

Comment: @Oleksa I'm not sure what you mean. The second part of my answer allows you to use wildcards. And you can add as many criteria as you like.

Comment: @P.b I might be wrong but I thought that your example has to be entered as an array formula (using ctrl-shift-enter). The extra INDEX allows it to be entered as a standard formula.

Comment: Ok, good addition if true. I'm unable to test with an older Excel version.

Comment: @P.b I have just tested and yes, your suggestion only works if entered as an array formula (entered using CSE). Where I work, everyone breaks array formulas and then asks me why it's not working anymore, so I try to avoid them like the plague.

Answer (score 0):

Would you be open to filtering the data first?

```
=FILTER($C:$C,
ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Person",$A:$A))*
($F:$F=12345)
)
```

Comment: The calculation should work in a heterogenous environment (MSO, LO, OnlyOffice etc), so trying to minimise using non-standard functions...

Comment: @Oleksa Where in your question did you mention that? @spiela adding `@` in front of your formula `=@FILTER($C:$C,
ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Person",$A:$A))*
($F:$F=12345)
)` will result in the first row of the returned array, just like MATCH would do

Comment: FILTER function is available neither LO, nor OnlyOffice, I mean. Even in legacy MSO it is not available as well.